# iPhone SDK: Using the NavigationController, how to invoke another view?

Tags: iphone

I am using a NavigationController and I want to be able to put another view on the stack in relation to some event. I am not sure what the call is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, it's very rare you'll be handling UIView objects directly for application flow.

What you want to do is create a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is the owner of a view. You then push the view controller (and in doing so it's associated view) to the top by calling your UINavigationController's [`pushViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) method.

You might want to read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), more specifically, the section on the [Navigation Controller](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1). The guide explains the basic principles of how it works, and gives code examples of common tasks.